# What is the least number of servers I need to deploy a Exchange 2007 CCR (Clustered Continuois Replication) cluster?

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-cluster

I've read that at the very least to get an Exchange 2007 CCR cluster for fail over redundancy, you need 2 servers running Exchange 2007 Ent and a 3rd server of any type as long as its running any Windows Server 2003 OS (for the file share witness).  Have others found this to be true?

Secondly, MS states that although its not necessary they recommend installing the file share witness onto a hub transport server.  The only reason they give is that it will give the messaging admin greater control over the cluster, I'm not sure what that implies.  I'm not going to use a hub transport server for the file share witness so what will I be missing out on or what problems might I run into?  Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, you will have one active node and one passive node. The file share witness can be on any Windows server without negatively impacting on you CCR cluster.

The recommendation is more in terms of administration where duties are seperated eg. the Exchange admins do not have access to non Exchange servers etc.

Comment: Oh God thank you, I've been sweating this for days :D  Though I've seen websites claim you COULD do it this way I've never seen a diagram where the exact build of two exchange servers and one non-exchange file share witness are being used.  Thanks for the piece of mind, now I just have to order the hardware and get the thing to work :)  Most likely will be posting again at that point haha, have a great holiday!